# How does city healing work?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

When laying siege to a city is it possible to predict how much it is going to heal for on the enemies turn? Is it always a percentage of the city's maximum health or does it have some random element to it? How do defensive enhancements modify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a city build a wall while I was besieging it. It was at half health, and appeared to heal ~25 health. So, I believe building a defensive structure causes the health to remain at the same percent, which means healing some. From what I saw, the city was healing 20 health per turn both before and after the construction of the wall. Since walls boost max health, I find it most likely that healing is simply the flat 20 health (not percentage base), and instead of increasing the heal amount, the defenses are increasing the *value* of that healing, by decreasing the damage taken.